# How do I get the last touched segment in UISegmentControl to be highlighted in Swift?

Tags: xcode, swift, uisegmentedcontrol

I have this UISegmentControl with three segments and I press on one of them and it highlights. Then I press a button to hide the UISegmentControl and when I go back to the UISegmentControl the last segment that I pressed is no longer highlighted. How would I fix that?

```
func pressSettingsButton() {

    var customSC = UISegmentedControl()
    let items = ["blue", "orange", "red"]

    customSC = UISegmentedControl(items: items)
    customSC.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
    customSC.frame = (CGRectMake(self.view!.bounds.width/2 - 540/2, 65 * scaleFactor, 250, 30))

    customSC.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
    customSC.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    customSC.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    customSC.addTarget(self, action: #selector(GameScene.changeColor(_:)), forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
    self.view!.addSubview(customSC)
 }

      if node.name == "settings" {
        //shows UISegmentControl

        pressSettingsButton()
    }


    if node.name == "closesettings" {
        //close segment control

        customSC.hidden = true 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are setting your segmented control to 0 each time you call pressSettingsButton:

```
customSC.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
```

You could call it with a setting for this value that you store in your game (i.e. pressSettingsButton(colorIndex)) and then set the segmented control to that value instead like so:

```
customSC.selectedSegmentIndex = colorIndex
```

The formatting looks off however, so maybe you could provide more detail.